# Keyboard with search icon

Tags: android, search, keyboard, icons, imeoptions

I have a `SearchActivty` in my application on which I have an `EditText` and a `Button` to search the items. I want the search icon to be displayed in keyboard for this `EditText`.

Right now I've `imeOption = "actionSearch"` inside my `EditText` layout which is right now giving "search" as text in the keyboard. I want instead of text there should be an icon. IS it possible to set search icon on place of text in keyboard. If yes then please help.

**My `EditText` in layout is :**

```
<EditText 
     android:id="@+id/txtUser"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="type name here"
     android:inputType="text"
     android:singleLine="true"       
     android:imeOptions="actionSearch"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, its not possible.  The keyboard itself decides what should be shown where.  Some keyboards will implement images for various imeOptions, some won't.  But there's no way to force it.